# Stock mail app not showing email body

Tags: stock-email-app

I use the stock mail app to check a number of email accounts, including my Hotmail account (via IMAP).

Until recently my email worked just fine but now when I read an email the body of the email doesn't load. I can see the from name and email and the subject, but I don't get the content of the email.

As far as I'm aware I haven't changed anything. And other accounts load the complete email.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like no one else has had this problem I tinkered for several hours... AND I fixed it. The action that fixed this bug was removing the Hotmail (Which is actually called Outlook online now) account and adding it again.